# Email Open Tracking for Email-to-Case Reply And case Emails

Tags: email, administration, email2case

I've been researching, how can we enable **Email open tracking**, if we are sending email from case.

I checked the link [Considerations for Email Open Tracking](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=emailadmin_tracking_considerations.htm&type=5)

According to 3rd point  email can't be tracked

> "The email is sent from Cases or from an email that uses Email-to-Case"

Is there any other way to do so or something I am missing ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue and I'm afraid this is unachievable via standard email tracking for emails sent from within a Case record. There are a couple of articles saying it's not possible (e.g. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000328073&type=1&mode=1).

Regards,
Mateusz :)